# Passing a Port-Address to function

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, avr

How do I retrieve the pointer from this definition?

The Definition: `#define SPIE    (*(SPI_t *) 0x0AC0)  /* Serial Peripheral Interface */` and the adress of the register is `0x0AC0`. SPI_t is a struct defined further down in the header file:

```
/* Serial Peripheral Interface */
typedef struct SPI_struct
{
    register8_t CTRL;  /* Control Register */
    register8_t INTCTRL;  /* Interrupt Control Register */
    register8_t STATUS;  /* Status Register */
    register8_t DATA;  /* Data Register */
} SPI_t;
```

I really have no idea what is going on in the define. It looks like the pointer is being casted to the struct, but I'm not sure.
What I need is a `uint16_t*` pointer, so I can pass it on to a function. Using `spi mySpi( &PORTB);` with the constructor being

```
spi::spi(volatile uint16_t* reg)
{
    spiReg = reg;
} //spi
```

results in `Error   1   no matching function for call to 'spi::spi(PORT_t*)'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The define `#define SPIE (*(SPI_t *) 0x0AC0` is creating a symbolic name (SPIE) for 4 bytes of memory located at 0x0AC0. That is 0x0AC0 is the control register, 0x0AC1 is the interrupt control register, and so on.

Your C code should be able to reference these like so

```
SPIE.CTRL = 7; // set low 3 bits for some reason
SPIE.INTCTRL = 4; // set 3rd bit, disable all others
```

To get the address, you could "take the address" as usual: `&SPIE`. This will be 0x0AC0 when evaluated, but will have the type `SPI_t *`.

Your constructor takes a 16-bit register, but SPIE defines only 8-bit registers, so I don't think its going to work out so well.

Comment: Not quite what I wanted in the first place, but instead a way better way. Thank you so much!